# How to implement google image search in IOS application?

Tags: ios, image, api

I want to implement google image search in my IOS app, there would be a search bar in which user can enter anything to get images related, like mouse and this will result by giving images of mouse, then those images will be displayed in my app.
Is there any API or something else which gives google images search result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a Query to Google Servers and then you receive all information as a json file.

For more information: https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide?hl=de&csw=1

This is the URL for searching for "fuzzy monkey" and returning 8 result (rsz=8)

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey&rsz=8

Comment: I found a url
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey
this gives me related search with images but it gives me only 4 results at a time

Comment: Just scroll down to `Optional URL arguments` there you can find the parameter (rsz) to specify the number of results.

Comment: can you please write down the url with rsz parameter

Comment: only 8 results at a time. How to get more images?

Comment: change the parameter: &rsz to the number of images you want to get (for instance if you want 20 images: &rsz=20

Comment: It says API is no longer available

Comment: Yeah, because this API is deprecated since 2011. It looks like they now totally killed the API. But there is a much more powerful API where you can do all of the stuff from the old one and much more: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/?hl=de

Comment: @rahul link you posted indicates that is not longer available.any new solution rather than cuatom search api?