# Get similar image url from Google similar image search API response iOS

Tags: objective-c, api, search, image-processing, image-recognition

I am working on making the app for showing similar images of special image.
so I used Google image search API and got the response from this API.

https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=http://www.celebrityviplounge.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/contouring.jpg

But there is no way to get similar image URLs from its response on iOS.
Is there any way to do it?
If have experience on it, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your question:

> [How to implement google image search in IOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932365/how-to-implement-google-image-search-in-ios-application)

Comment: I don't want the results of search text. search should be done by the image. This one is for searching by search key, not by image.
If you have other solution please let me know.
I want to parse the response of it. or want to get response with JSON format.

Comment: I have the url of the image. I want to redirect its url to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images

From Googling, I saw its api can get image url as a parameter. But couldn't find any sample. Have you ever experienced it?
Please let me know how to use image url as a parameter. 
Thanks